# RegEx syntax for selecting second occurence of characters

Tags: r, regex, string, syntax

I have a relatively simple problem but can't figure out the right syntax in RegEx.
I have multiple experiment names as strings in various formats, e.g. **SEF001DT45** or **BV004MF**.

What I want to do is to select the second occurence of two letters after a numeric value (**DT** and **MF** in this case).

I figured out that
`[A-Z]{2}`
solves my problem only halfway. How do I get the proper substrings?

Comment: i don't see how your desired result matches your description `second occurence of two letters after a numeric value`, that sounds like for `1ABCD` the answer would be CD (or even BC)

Comment: I should have clarified that the source format is usually [char*x][num*3][char*2]([num*y])

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR**: Generally, you can get the second occurrence of a `PATTERN` using one of the following

```r
sub('.*?PATTERN.*?(PATTERN).*', '\\1', x)
stringr::str_match(x, 'PATTERN.*?(PATTERN)')[,2]
regmatches(x, regexpr('PATTERN.*?\\KPATTERN', x, perl=TRUE))
```

**Details**

You can use

```r
x <- c('SEF001DT45','BV004MF')
sub('.*?[A-Z]{2}.*?([A-Z]{2}).*', '\\1', x)
## => [1] "DT" "MF"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/Zv9UMl) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z4xcuX/2). The point here is to match up to the second occurrence of the pattern, capture it, and then match the rest, and replace with the backreference to the capturing group value.

Note that `sub` will perform a single search and replace operation, and this is fine since the regex here requires the whole string match.

*Details*:

- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `[A-Z]{2}` - two uppercase ASCII letters
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `([A-Z]{2})` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value): two uppercase ASCII letters
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible.

You can achieve this with a simpler regex using `stringr::str_match`:

```r
x <- c('SEF001DT45','BV004MF')
library(stringr)
results <- stringr::str_match(x, '[A-Z]{2}.*?([A-Z]{2})')
results[,2] ## Get Group 1 values
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/D9rrcK).

Or, with `regmatches`/`regexpr` in base R:

```r
x <- c('SEF001DT45','BV004MF')
results <- regmatches(x, regexpr('[A-Z]{2}.*?\\K[A-Z]{2}', x, perl=TRUE))
results
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/n8J4tX).

Here, `[A-Z]{2}.*?\\K[A-Z]{2}` finds the first two uppercase ASCII letters, then matches any zero or more chars (other than line break chars since the PCRE engine is used) as few as possible, and then `\K` discards the matched text and the `[A-Z]{2}` at the end of the pattern matches the second occurrence of the two-letter chunk. `regexpr` only finds the first match.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailled explaination! It gave me a lot of insights to the syntax! :)

Comment: @AhmetMera If you are interested to learn more about `\1`, then see [Numbered Backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html). These are special "constructs", placeholders, used in replacement patterns to refer to the text captured into some capturing group.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution, based on `stringr::str_extract` and lookaround:

```r
library(stringr)

strings <- c("SEF001DT45", "BV004MF")

str_extract(strings, "(?<=\\d)[:upper:]{2}")

#> [1] "DT" "MF"
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:

```
s <- c("SEF001DT45", "BV004MF")
sub("[A-Z]+\\d+([A-Z]{2}).*", "\\1", s)
#sub("[A-Z]+[0-9]+([A-Z]{2}).*", "\\1", s) #Alternative
#[1] "DT" "MF"
```

Where `[A-Z]` matches characters, `\\d` numbers, `[A-Z]{2}` the two characters and `.*` for the remaining rest.
With `()` the content which is inserted with `\\1` is selected.
Or something more strict about *the second occurence of two letters*:

```
sub(".*?[A-Z]{2}[0-9]+([A-Z]{2}).*", "\\1", s)
#[1] "DT" "MF"
```

When only the two characters after the first number should be extracted is enough:

```
regmatches(s, regexpr("(?<=\\d)[A-Z]{2}", s, perl=TRUE))
#[1] "DT" "MF"
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! So if i understood this correctly, the \\1 operator selects the value that is enclosed in round brackets? This was basically the part that I struggled with..

Comment: Yes. And you can make more than one selection what can be used than with `\\2`, `\\3`, ...

Answer (score 3):

Base R:

```
# Using capture groups:
gsub(
  ".*\\d{2}(\\w{2}).*",
  "\\1",
  x
)

# Input data:
x <- c(
  'SEF001DT45',
  'BV004MF'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R trick is `strsplit`

```
> sapply(strsplit(s, split = "\\d+"), `[[`, 2)
[1] "DT" "MF"
```

or `gsub`

```
> gsub("^.*?(?<=\\d)(\\D+).*", "\\1", s, perl = TRUE)
[1] "DT" "MF"
```